# How to know currently logged in username in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to know currently logged in username in Oracle SQL, if we are dealing with multiple users within the same DB, it is little bit confusing to understand!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using this query we can get currently logged in user

```
select user from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways.

---

**Option 1** 
Use the V$SESSION view.

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM V$SESSION;
```

**Option 2** 
This one gives all the detailed information because there are times that you have to locate locked sessions.

```
select
       substr(a.spid,1,9) pid,
       substr(b.sid,1,5) sid,
       substr(b.serial#,1,5) ser#,
       substr(b.machine,1,6) box,
       substr(b.username,1,10) username,
--     b.server,
       substr(b.osuser,1,8) os_user,
       substr(b.program,1,30) program
from v$session b, v$process a
where
b.paddr = a.addr
and type='USER'
order by os_user,username;
```

Comment: This will return information for _all_ running sessions, but the question was how to return it for the _current_ session.